# Spring Boot RestTemplate Calling an API returns forbidden 403

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I followed spring boot example ([example here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)) to consume a rest call and it worked fine with calling the api :  http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random.

But then I tried to call GiantBomb's api call and I keep getting forbidden 403 error. Although I tried this with other api calls as well and they result in 403 as well (like games db api call [here](http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men))

the api call is like :
http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[my_key]&format=json&query="halo"&resources=game&field_list=deck,id,image,name,platform

Here is my main method with spring boot config.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationExecuter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationExecuter.class, args);
        String url = GiantBombApiInfo.API_BASE_URL + "search/?api_key=" + GiantBombApiInfo.API_KEY + "&format=json&query=" + "\"" + "halo" + "\"" +"&resources=game"
                +"&field_list=deck,id,image,name,platform";
        System.out.println(url);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Game[]> response = template.getForEntity(url , Game[].class);
        Game[] games = response.getBody();
    }
}
```

Which API_BASE_URL is http://www.giantbomb.com/api/. I printed the url I'm trying to call and accessing it with the browser works just fine.

The error happens exactly when I call template.getForEntity(url , Game[].class); meaning I don't even get to the part to use the body.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
        at core.exec.ApplicationExecuter.main(ApplicationExecuter.java:38)
        ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
        at core.exec.ApplicationExecuter.main(ApplicationExecuter.java:38)
```

the pom file is as bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>appTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I can provide the code for Game class which would consume the json result also but as I said I get the error before this even happens. But please let me know if you need more details for an answer.

Could you please tell me what is missing in the code?
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "/" after "search" looks a little fishy to me.  Typically the query portion of the URL will not be preceded by a forward slash; rather just the "?."  Also, you might try single ticks surrounding halo ('halo').

```
http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[my_key]&format=json&query="halo"&resources=game&field_list=deck,id,image,name,platform
```

However, after looking at the [developer forum](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/api-developers-3017/api-call-throws-error-403-forbidden-1496714/#9) it appears your URL may be formed properly but you may be facing similar issues to those mentioned in this article.

Comment: Thanks @neal ! based on the discussion on the forum, I had to set a user-agent.